# How to figure out Line-in or Mic-in

Tags: audio, input

I've been searching around for a soundcard to stream audio into my computer from an outside source, since my current motherboard supports mic-in instead of line-in, it sounds like garbo. However, on my motherboard's website, it says "Line-in/Mic-in" [1] (under Back Panel Connectors.) I also noticed on many of the soundcards and motherboards that they also say "Line-in/Mic-in." I was wondering if anybody could reccomend a solution or figure a way to search for a specifically line-in solution.

[1] : https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-X99-Gaming-5P-rev-10#sp

Comment: What do you mean by "garbo"? Do you mean clipping and overdriving?

Comment: yeah I meant clipping, really weird clipping. almost like an ocean wave hitting my speakers at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your link under the I/O section it says there is a audio gain control switch. Make sure it is toggled to "Line"

Comment: I'm gonna be honest with you, I've been trying to look into this for a couple months now. not once did I think that it'd be a solution like that (while it does say gain switch, it's actually software controlled,) but all I had to do was read the product page better. you've made my week, thanks a ton.